# Paginination for Query in Suitelet script

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am new to Netsuite,

I am fetching the records through the Query,but the query limit is 5000 so i am adding the pagination for query records,

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */
var
    log,
    query,
    serverWidget;

define(['N/log', 'N/record', 'N/query', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/format', 'N/currentRecord', 'N/file', 'N/encode', 'N/url', 'N/http'], main);

function main(logModule, recordModule, queryModule, serverWidgetModule, formatModule, currentRecordModule, file, encode, url, http) {
    log = logModule;
    record = recordModule;
    query = queryModule;
    serverWidget = serverWidgetModule;
    format = formatModule;
    currentRecord = currentRecordModule;

    function onRequest(context) {
        // Create a form.       
         
        var form = serverWidget.createForm({
            title: 'Custom Unrealized Exchange Rate Gains and Losses - Bill, Bill Payment & Invoice',
            hideNavBar: false
        });
      
        // Add the filter fields.
        var queryField = form.addField({
            id: 'custpage_field_query',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.LONGTEXT,
            label: 'Query'
        });
        var periodFromField = form.addField({
            id: 'custpage_field_periodfrom',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: 'From',
            source: 'accountingperiod'
        });
        var periodToField = form.addField({
            id: 'custpage_field_periodto',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: 'To',
            source: "accountingperiod"
        });
        var subsidiaryField = form.addField({
            id: 'custpage_field_subsidiary',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: 'Subsidiary'
            //source: "subsidiary"
        });
      
        var currencyField = form.addField({
            id: 'custpage_field_currency',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            label: 'Base Currency'
        });
      
        var rangeField = form.addField({
            id: 'custpage_field_range',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label: 'Range'
        });
      
        var rangeHiddenField = form.addField({
            id: 'custpage_field_range_text',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.LONGTEXT,
            label: 'Range Text'
        });
      
        rangeField.addSelectOption({value : 0,text : ''});rangeField.addSelectOption({value : 1,text : '1500'});rangeField.addSelectOption({value : 2,text : '3000'});rangeField.addSelectOption({value : 3,text : '5000'});
      
        // Add a submit button and export button
        form.addSubmitButton({
            label: 'Refresh'
        });
        form.addButton({
            id: 'custpage_nextpage_btn',
            label: 'NextPage'
        });

      var subsidiaryqueryData = "select s.id,s.name,s.parent,s.currency from subsidiary s";
      
       // Run the query.
      var subsidiaryqueryResults = query.runSuiteQL({
        query: subsidiaryqueryData,
      });
      var subsidiaryrecords = subsidiaryqueryResults.asMappedResults();

      //subsidiaryrecords.push({"name":"Veeva Systems Inc. (Consolidated)","id":"(1,2,5,6,8,58,59,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,39,42,52,9,54,55,56,19,21,12,13,15,16,10,11,66,65,68,70)",                             "currency": "6","parent": "6"});
      //
      
     // subsidiaryrecords.push({"name":"Veeva Systems Inc. (Consolidated)", "id":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,19,21,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,39,41,42,43,47,48,49,52,54,55,56,57,58,59,63,64,65,66,68,69,70", "currency": "6","parent": "6"});
      
      
      log.debug({title:'subsidiaryData',details:subsidiaryrecords});

    var fillSubsidiary=subsidiaryrecords;       
      if(fillSubsidiary.length != 0) {        
        for(var i in fillSubsidiary) {
            subsidiaryField.addSelectOption({
                value : fillSubsidiary[i].id,
                text : fillSubsidiary[i].name
            });
          }
      }

        // Make the field required.
        periodFromField.isMandatory = true;
        periodToField.isMandatory = true;
        subsidiaryField.isMandatory = true;
        queryField.updateDisplayType({
            displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
        });
        currencyField.updateDisplayType({
            displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
        });
        rangeHiddenField.updateDisplayType({
            displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
        });
        form.clientScriptModulePath = '../SuiteScripts/excel_export_clientscript.js';
        periodFromField.defaultValue = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_periodfrom;
        periodToField.defaultValue = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_periodto;
        subsidiaryField.defaultValue = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_subsidiary;
        currencyField.defaultValue = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_currency;
        queryField.defaultValue = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_query;
        rangeField.defaultValue = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_range;
        rangeHiddenField.defaultValue = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_range_text;
       
        // If the form has been submitted...
        if (context.request.method == 'POST') {
            try {
                var periodFromId = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_periodfrom;
                var periodToId = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_periodto;
                var subsidiaryId = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_subsidiary;
                var basecurrency = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_currency;
                var subsidaryName = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_query;
                var rangeValue = context.request.parameters.custpage_field_range_text;
             //     var currentRecObj   = context.currentRecord;
              //    var subsidiaryfieldName = currentRecObj.getText('custpage_field_subsidiary');
                log.debug({title:'subsidiaryfieldNameSL',details:subsidaryName})

                log.debug({title:'rangeValueText',details:rangeValue})

                if (periodFromId) {
                    var fromaccperiodObj = record.load({
                        type: 'accountingperiod',
                        id: periodFromId
                    });
                    if (fromaccperiodObj) {
                        var periodStartDate = fromaccperiodObj.getValue({
                            fieldId: 'startdate'
                        });
                    }
                    var periodFromDate = format.format({
                        value: periodStartDate,
                        type: format.Type.DATE
                    });
                    var periodFromFormat = new Date(periodFromDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                }

                if (periodToId) {
                    var toaccperiodObj = record.load({
                        type: 'accountingperiod',
                        id: periodToId
                    });
                    if (toaccperiodObj) {
                        var periodEndDate = toaccperiodObj.getValue({
                            fieldId: 'enddate'
                        });
                    }
                    var periodToDate = format.format({
                        value: periodEndDate,
                        type: format.Type.DATE
                    });
                    var periodToFormat = new Date(periodToDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                }
              //,CASE WHEN (t.exchangerate !=cr1.Exchangerate) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as " + UICurrencyChanges + ",t.exchangerate as TransExRate,cr1.Exchangerate as " + sourceexchangeratealias + ",
/*** Assign Column Name for Report in the variable and assign the variable to the Query. Reason - Onside the Query Space is not taken" ***/
                var trannoalias = '"Source Transaction Number"';
                var trantypealias = '"Source Transaction Type"';
                var periodalias = '"Unrealized Gain / Loss Posting Period"';
                var datealias = '"Source Transaction Date"';
                var sourceexchangeratealias = '"Beginning Fx Rate"';
                var endingexchangeratealias = '"End FX Rate"';
                var currencyalias = '"Foreign Currency"';
                var currencybalancealias = '"Foreign Currency Balance"';
                var netgainalias = '"Net Gain / Loss"';
                var consolidatedexchangerate='"Consolidated Exchange Rate"';                
                var consolidatedFxRate='"Consolidated Foreign Currency"';
                var consolidatedgain='"Consolidated Gain / Loss"';
              
              //CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR ( t.TranDate, 'DD' ))  >= 1 THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END as  " + sourceexchangeratealias + ",
              var flDate = new Date(periodEndDate).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
 var n = flDate.toString();
              

flDate = "'"+n+"'";
                var queryData = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROWNUM AS RN, * FROM ( select t.closedate, CASE when t.AbbrevType = 'INV' THEN 'Accounts Receivable' ELSE 'Accounts Payable' End as Account, BUILTIN.DF(t.Entity) as Name, BUILTIN.DF(tl.subsidiary) as Subsidiary, t.Tranid AS SourceTransactionNumber, t.TranDate as SourceTransactionDate, CASE when t.AbbrevType = 'BILL' THEN 'BILL' WHEN t.AbbrevType = 'INV' THEN 'INVOICE' ELSE 'BILL PAYMENT' End as SourceTransactionType, ap.periodname AS UnrealizedGainPostingPeriod, CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY')) AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY')) AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END as BeginningFxRate, cr2.Exchangerate as EndFXRate, BUILTIN.DF(t.currency) as ForeignCurrency, Round(ForeignTotal, 2) as ForeignCurrencyBalance, Round( ( ( cr2.Exchangerate - CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY')) AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY')) AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END ) * ForeignTotal ), 2 ) AS NetGainLoss, cexr.averagerate as ConsolidatedExchangeRate, Round( ( ( cr2.Exchangerate - CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY')) AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY')) AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END ) * (ForeignTotal * cexr.averagerate) ), 2 ) AS ConsolidatedGainLoss, from Transaction t INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl ON (tl.Transaction = t.ID) INNER JOIN Subsidiary sb ON sb.id = tl.subsidiary INNER JOIN AccountingPeriod ap ON ( ( ap.id BETWEEN (320) AND (320) ) AND ap.isposting = 'T' ) INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr1 ON ( cr1.BaseCurrency = sb.currency AND cr1.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency AND ( cr1.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.startdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') ) ) INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr2 ON ( cr2.BaseCurrency = sb.currency AND cr2.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency AND ( cr2.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.enddate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') ) ) LEFT JOIN CurrencyRate cr3 ON ( cr3.BaseCurrency = 1 AND cr3.TransactionCurrency = sb.currency AND ( cr3.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(t.TranDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') ) ) INNER JOIN consolidatedexchangerate cexr ON ( cexr.postingperiod = t.PostingPeriod AND cexr.fromsubsidiary = tl.subsidiary AND cexr.tosubsidiary = 1 ) Where ( ( (t.AbbrevType = ('INV')) OR (t.AbbrevType = ('BILL')) ) ) AND (tl.MainLine = 'T') AND (tl.subsidiary IN (1)) AND ( (t.CloseDate IS NULL) OR (t.CloseDate >= TO_DATE("+flDate+", 'YYYY-MM-DD')) )) ) WHERE ( RN BETWEEN 5001 AND 10000 )";
              
                log.debug({
                    title: 'queryData',
                    details: queryData
                });

                // Run the query.
                var queryResults = query.runSuiteQL({
                    query: queryData,
                });

                // Get the mapped results.
                var beginTime = new Date().getTime();
                var records = queryResults.asMappedResults();
                var endTime = new Date().getTime();
                var elapsedTime = endTime - beginTime;

                // If records were returned...
                if (records.length > 0) {
                    // Create a sublist for the results.
                    var resultsSublist = form.addSublist({
                        id: 'results_sublist',
                        label: 'Results (' + records.length + ' records retrieved in ' + elapsedTime + 'ms)',
                        type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST
                    });

                    // Get the column names.
                    var columnNames = Object.keys(records[0]);

                    // Loop over the column names...
                    for (i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {

                        // Add the column to the sublist as a field.
                        resultsSublist.addField({
                            id: 'custpage_results_sublist_col_' + i,
                            type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                            label: columnNames[i]
                        });

                    }

                    // Add the records to the sublist...
                    for (r = 0; r < records.length; r++) {

                        // Get the record.
                        var recordvalue = records[r];

                        // Loop over the columns...
                        for (c = 0; c < columnNames.length; c++) {

                            // Get the column name.
                            var column = columnNames[c];

                            // Get the column value.
                            var value = recordvalue[column];
                            if (value != null) {
                                value = value.toString();
                            }

                            // Add the column value.
                            resultsSublist.setSublistValue({
                                id: 'custpage_results_sublist_col_' + c,
                                line: r,
                                value: value
                            });

                        }

                    }

                } else {
                    // Create a sublist for the results.
                    var noresultsSublist = form.addSublist({
                        id: 'noresults_sublist',
                        label: 'No data available.',
                        type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST
                    });

                }

            } catch (e) {}
        }

        if (records != '') {
          log.debug({title:'subsidiaryIdexp',details:subsidaryName})
        
          var subsidiaryIdData = "'"+subsidiaryId+"'";
          var subsidiaryNameData = "'"+subsidaryName+"'";
            form.clientScriptModulePath = '../SuiteScripts/excel_export_clientscript.js';
            var exportBtn = form.addButton({
                id: 'custpage_export_btn',
                label: 'Export',
                functionName: "excelDownload(" + periodFromId + "," + periodToId + "," + subsidiaryIdData + ","+basecurrency+","+subsidiaryNameData+");"
            })
        }

        // Display the form.
        context.response.writePage(form);
    }


    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };
}
```

The above code work perfectly, but the question is is it possible to add dynamic pagination in suitelet.

is there any sample for pagination?

I am trying to add nextpage button and when click on that button the next page should popup but it failed and the page is refreshing entirely.

Thanks in advance